# Efficiently calculate time since last transaction

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a large table of transactions identified by user id and date. For each user's last transaction, I would like to calculate the time elapsed since the previous transaction. Is there something like a lag operator I can use to do this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110412/120504

Comment: Thanks again, Rob. That's exactly what I was looking for. If you want to turn that into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of using Window Aggregate functions to accomplish LEAD and LAG in Teradata [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110412/120504).

Comment: Please don't posts answers that are just a link to another question.  Flag these questions as a duplicate or vote to close when you get enough rep.

Comment: This is a different application of WA functions, so I would keep this around.