# TOAD, date values, flag, teradata, prior record

Tags: date, toad, teradata

I have a large data set with start dates and stop dates in each record.

There is one unique field value we can call Uniq1.

Each record has a Uniq1.

Other fields can be called MID, PrDl, PsDl.

Uniq1, MID are Integer.

What I need to do is output a dataset (thinking SelfJoin) from this dataset that has flagged each record with a yes or no, (1 or 0), where a 1 = a record whose stop date is followed by another record’s start date within 30 days of the stop date.

This would be specific to the MId, so that if MId 1 had 6 records chronologically and the second record was an admission within 30 days of the previous records stop date the second record would be flagged = 1 while the initial record would be flagged 0 and among the 4 subsequent records for MId 1 there are no other similar 30 day occurrences, so they are flagged = 0 as well.

Ideally, I would like the following output, for example:

Uniq1  MId     Start      Stop       #Days          Flag           PrDl           PsDl

123    1    1/24/2010   2/4/2010                    0           CharValue        CharValue

321    1    2/25/2010   3/5/2010      21            1           CharValue        CharValue

789    1    6/21/2010   6/28/2010    116            0           CharValue        CharValue

Notice that the # days between Uniq1-123 and Uniq1-321 are 21 and therefore flag =1, however, between Uniq1-321 and Uniq1-789 the # of days are 116 and the flag = 0.

Any advice would be most appreciated, thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095338/compare-3-consecutive-rows-in-a-table/13110412). You should be able to derive your solution from the SQL there. If you get stuck, edit your question with your SQL and I will try to help.