# SQL to compare records (status change) in table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that contains history of a claim. Basically I'm looking at status changes and dates. Whenever someone updates a claim, the new row is loaded into the table I'm showing below. What I'm trying to obtain is all of the status changes for the column "c_sta_clm" I want to be able to capture the date "row_begin_dt" and both status change (PC to AC) & (AC to TE).

Any guidance on how to make this simple is hugely appreciated. I was thinking of making two volatile tables and joining on C_CLM, taking min status dates and comparing etc...

```
row_begin_dt                user                    c_clm          c_sta_clm
2009-10-08  ?       C5S2M                         09050012            PC
2009-10-24  ?       C5S2M                         09050012            AC
2009-10-28  ?       C1CMH                         09050012            AC
2010-10-30  ?       C1CMH                         09050012            AC
2011-05-19  ?       A9709                         09050012            AC
2011-06-09  ?       C6JEC                         09050012            AC
2011-10-07  ?       DAJ07                         09050012            TE
2011-11-04  ?       DAJ07                         0905001             TE
```

Comment: SQL is the language. What DBMS is this for?

Comment: First and, probably, last time I'll ever get to add the "Teradata" tag to a question.

Comment: May I suggest looking at the answer to this **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095338/compare-3-consecutive-rows-in-a-table)**. You should be able to use Window Aggregate functions with the proper windowing (ROWS BETWEEN) to accomplish this. Post **[what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)** and I will help you from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the records for 2009-10-24 and 2011-10-07.

```
select
    row_begin_dt,
    user,
    c_clm,
    c_sta_clm,
    -- Find the c_sta_clm of the previous row
    max(c_sta_clm) over (partition by c_clm order by row_begin_dt rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_c_sta_clm
from claims
-- Include only records which have a c_sta_clm different to that of the previous row
qualify c_sta_clm <> prev_c_sta_clm
```

Answer (score 1):

One general way to do this is using correlated subqueries:

```
select
from (select c.*,
             (select top 1 from claims c2 where c2.c_clm = c.c_clm a and c2.row_begin_dt > c.row_begin_dt order by row_begin_dt
             ) as next_sta_clm
      from claim c2
     ) c
where next_sta_clm <> c_sta_clm
```

In many databases, you can do the same thing with the `lag` or `lead` function, but no all databases support them.

Comment: I've tried this using actual table names but it's a bit confusing with the "extra" from statement...                                                                 select *
from (select c.*,
             (select top 1 from pearl_p.TLTC900_CLM_PRSST c2 where c2.c_clm = c.c_clm a and c2.row_begin_dt > c.row_begin_dt order by row_begin_dt
             ) as next_sta_clm
      from pearl_p.TLTC900_CLM_PRSST  c2
     ) c
where next_sta_clm <> c_sta_clm

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select ToRecord.row_begin_dt From ClaimHistory FromRecord
inner join ClaimHistory ToRecord On ToRecord.c_clm = FromRecord.c_clm and ToRecord.row_begin_dt > FromRecord.row_begin_dt and ToRecord.c_sta_claim = 'AC'
Where FromRecord.c_sta_claim = 'PC'
```

would get PC to AC, didnlt know whether user column was significant, but bolting it in should be trivial. Seeing as you didn't say which DBMS, sql may require a twiddle.

Also this would pick up something like PC to XX to AC, which you didnt say anything about.

Comment: It's Teradata SQL. I think there may be an OLAP function as well. I'm trying to capture the status changes in the correct order like PC to AC then AC to TE for this data sample there would only be the two.

Comment: So you ony want PC directky followed by AC? i.e. no intermediate states?

Comment: it would be the first PC to the first AC and the last AC to the first TE

Comment: That's not going to be funny. If you are going to be running this a lot, or less frequently over large amounts of data, if I were you I'd seriously consider using a trigger to some sort of StatusChangeHistory table.