# The Best Approach for this Data Transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, data-mining, teradata

I'm simplifying reality for the sake of simplicity...

I have a table with millions of Temperature observations:  ObservationID, LocationID, Observation_Date, Temperature

I want to write a query, but derive additional columns as well,

ObservationID,
LocationID,
Observation_Date,
Temperature,
Temperature_At_Last_Observation,
Temperature_2_observations_ago,
Temperature_3_observations_ago,
Temperature_4_observations_ago,
..etc..

In reality this is much more complex, and I do have millions of rows in the table.  So I'm wondering *what approach would be the most efficient*.

Do I attack this from a recursion standpoint? Or since I'll have at least 15 new columns per row would that mean recursion would be inefficient?

Or do I stick with a set based approach, partitioning the observations into a sort order and then joining on LocationID?

Any suggestions?

And lucky for me, I also have a choice of loading the data into a Teradata platform or a SQL Server 2008R2 platform.

Comment: Are you familiar with CROSS APPLY?  That would be my first try.  Note: I don't know offhand what the most efficient way to solve this would be, I would probably keep hacking at it until I found something that satisfied me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with a SET based approach.

In SQL Server consider using LEAD() and LAG() with Window Aggregate functions.

In Teradata you can use Window Aggregate functions combined with ROW BETWEEN n PRECEDING and n PRECEDING to look back 'n' rows.

For an example in Teradata check out the response to the question [Compare 3 Consecutive Rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095338/compare-3-consecutive-rows-in-a-table/13110412#13110412).