# Select most recent increase in value column by ID

Tags: sql, subset, teradata

I am attempting a simple subset but am having a little trouble with simultaneously applying both of my conditions. I am looking to select, for each unique ID, the most recent record where the value column increased. For example, here is a simplified version of my data.

```
ID| Date | Value
A  1/1/17  100
A  1/2/17  185
A  1/3/17  40
A  1/4/17  100
A  1/5/17  30
B  1/3/17  40
B  1/4/17  30
B  1/5/17  65
B  1/6/17  80
B  1/7/17  0
B  1/8/17  0
```

While my desired output would be the row where the last increase of Value took place for each ID

```
ID| Date | Value
A  1/4/17  100
A  1/6/17  80
```

Does anybody have some insight on how I can achieve my desired output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   max(value) over (partition by id order by date rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_value
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_value < value
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In Teradata, you can also use `qualify` to remove one level of subqueries.

Comment: i don't think you can use `lag` in teradata.

Comment: I am having a little trouble with the part of the statement that uses my Value column. Perhaps it has to do with being in the lag function. The error reads "Data Type "Value" does not match a Defined Type name". I do see some pages which state that lag() does not exist in teradata.

Comment: LAG() and LEAD() are not implemented in the current releases of Teradata. With the correct windows defined, MAX() can be used to accomplish the same thing as demonstrated by vkp.

Comment: Can you elaborate how MAX can be used instead? If I simple just replace the lag() with MAX, I will just be creating a column which, for each ID, contains the max value for Value that ever occurred.

Comment: @vkp . . . That will always get me.  Why does Teradata support the functionality but not the functions?  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095338/compare-3-consecutive-rows-in-a-table/13110412#13110412 - See my answer to this question.

Comment: @RobPaller . . . I get that.  `LAG()` and `LEAD()` are ANSI standard.  There is no reason for Teradata to leave them out, especially given that they are merely syntactic sugar for functionality that is already implemented.

Comment: Understood @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select id,dt,value 
from (select t1.*
      ,max(case when t2.value<t1.value then t1.dt end) over(partition by t1.id) as max_dt 
      from (select t.*,min(dt) over(partition by id order by dt rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_dt
            from t
           ) t1
      join t t2 on t1.prev_dt=t2.dt and t1.id=t2.id             
     ) t
where max_dt=dt
```